# Why I Can not get data from mongodb database?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

It shows no error at all. Even cosole shows the database is connected. But it is not showing the data. When I go to http://localhost:5000/tasks it shows

> Cannot GET /tasks

what am I missing here?

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
require('dotenv').config()

const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.vwtzw.mongodb.net/${process.env.DB_NAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());

const port =5000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send('hello world!');
 });

const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true });

    client.connect(err => {
    const tasksCollection = client.db("VolunteerNetwork").collection("tasks");

    app.get('/tasks',(req, res) => {
        tasksCollection.find({})
        .toArray( ( err, documents) => {
          res.send(documents);
          console.log(documents);
          console.log('database connected');

        })
      })





});


app.listen(port);
```

after I run it shows -

- undefined
- database connected

mongo database name: VolunteerNetwork.tasks

Comment: Please don't paste images, provide formatted text instead.

Comment: Sorry, Edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works perfectly fine. It is an accurate approach.
My mistake was I did not give access to the username to edit/read the database in MongoDB. Giving the privilege made the work done.

Answer (score 0):

the get route is inside the connect method - try reorganizing the code so that you open the connection when a request is made

```
 const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
 const uri = `mongodb://localhost:27017`;

 const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true });
 router.get('/tasks',(req, res) => {
    client.connect(err => {
    const tasksCollection = client.db("VolunteerNetwork").collection("tasks");

    tasksCollection.find({})
    .toArray( ( err, documents) => {
       res.send(documents);
        console.log('database connected');
        console.log(documents);
       })
      })
});
```

Comment: with the same error? does hello world work for you?

Comment: Yes.hello world works for me. But, when I am trying to get the data from mongo using   http://localhost:5000/tasks it shows that error and  console.log(documents) returns undefined

Comment: sorry, I didnt see you edited the question - It seems like it cant find the collection "tasks".. is that the name (case sensitive)?

Comment: Sorry from my end because I did not make the question clear enough. I have added the picture of the database name now. I checked multiple times to check If I made any spelling mistakes but did not found any. It is case sensitive.

Comment: Is there anything in the err that returns?

Comment: No, nothing. At localhost:5000/tasks it shows Cannot GET /tasks and console.log(documents) returns undefined.

Comment: Ive  created a db and collection similar to yours, and edited my post with the exact code I'm running.. I do get results so I assume it might be a typo somewhere..

Comment: Wow!
I was feeling that it is a typo and tried 2 hours before asking the question. Okay, I am giving a full check again.

Comment: Thank you for your time. After your confirmation that my code was ok, I started looking for the other silly mistakes. Found that I added a new user for the database but did not give access to read/write the database. Dumb mistake!

Comment: It seemed like the answer would be something like that.. still strange that the err was empty though.. but glad you found it :)